# Setting Data via an AJAX call for D3 chart using Javascript and Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, d3.js

I am trying to set the data for D3jS using an AJAX call.

this is my C# method which returns a JSON string.

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            string jsonstring = string.Empty;
            string sessionId = string.Empty;
            try
            {   
                sessionId = GetDataSet.GetSessionId();
                var doc = GetDataSet.GenerateXDocument(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dashboard"], sessionId);
                jsonstring = GetDataSet.ConvertToJson(doc);

            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                var obj = new SAWSessionServiceSoapClient();
                obj.logoff(sessionId);
            }
            return jsonstring;

        }
```

This is my HTML

```
<div id="ReportContent" runat="server" style="border: 1px solid #58595d; border: 1px solid rgba(88, 89, 93, .3);"> </div>
```

My JavaScript code is as follows

```
var data = [{ "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Deposits", "Actual": 330393232.5, "Forecast": 495589848.75, "Target": 495589848.75 }, { "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Fee Based", "Actual": 111868709.42, "Forecast": 167803064.13, "Target": 167803064.13 }, { "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Lending", "Actual": 18146873.33, "Forecast": 27220309.995, "Target": 27220309.995 }];

        PageMethods.GetData(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);

        function OnSucceeded(result) {

            data = result;
            CreateChart();
        }

        function OnFailed(error) {
            alert(error.id);
        }

        function CreateChart() {

        var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {return d.Actual;})]) //change
            .range(["#f3c40e", "#7d6507"]);

        var width = 420,
            margin = 100, //add
            barHeight = 20;

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {return d.Actual;})]) //change
            .range([0, width]);

        var chart = d3.select('#ReportContent').append('svg')
            .attr("width", width + margin)
            .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);



            var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                .data(data, function(d) { return d.Actual; })
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + barHeight + ")");


            bar.append("rect")
                .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.Actual); }) //change
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return d.product == "Deposits" ? 10 : barHeight;
                })
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.Actual); }); //change

            bar.append("text")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end") //add
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Actual); }) //change
                .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.Product; });
        }
```

now my problem is that when I set static JSON string, the code works and I am able to get my simple bar graph but when I try the same with an AJAX request, it fails. to note, I call the code responsible to create my D3 simple bar graph once the AJAX request is completed and the data is available. I debugged the code to check if I am able to get the JSON string for the data and its affirmative. The only problem is I dont get to see any chart being created. I am not sure what I should do now :(

EDIT:

The below code is what works for me.

```
var data;
        PageMethods.GetData(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);

        function OnSucceeded(result) {
           // $x(document.getElementById("ReportContent_ReportContent")).innerHTML = "<div id='ajax_loading'> <img src='../Images/ajax-loader.gif' id='ajaxLoader' alt='loading...' title='Loading...' /></div>";
            //alert('success');
            data =JSON.parse(result);
            ChartCreate();
        }

        function OnFailed(error) {
            alert(error.id);
        }

        function ChartCreate() {
            var color = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Actual; })]) //change
                .range(["#f3c40e", "#7d6507"]);

            var width = 420,
                margin = 100, //add
                barHeight = 20;

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Actual; })]) //change
                .range([0, width]);

            var chart = d3.select('#ReportContent_ReportContent svg')
                .attr("width", width + margin)
                .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

            var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                .data(data, function(d) { return d.Actual; })
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

            bar.append("rect")
                .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.Actual); }) //change
                .attr("height", barHeight) //change
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.Actual); }); //change

            bar.append("text")
                .attr("text-anchor", "start") //add
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Actual); }) //change
                .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.Product; });
        }
```

Comment: I suspect that the `result` passed to `OnSucceeded` is not _exactly_ in the correct format. It does not contain any extra nesting, such that you have to do `data = result.data`? Is the value of `data` correct when you inspect it on the console?

Comment: I checked from debug, the data is in the correct format.Not sure what needs to be done :(

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. So `CreateChart` function is getting called? Is there any `svg` element in the DOM?

Comment: I even tried pulling all the D3 related code into a function and then calling it after OnSucceeded, but it wouldnt work. It would work when I sent the hard-coded data. The hard-coded data was nothing but the copied output from GetData() function call. Now, SVG element is set when the data is hard-coded, havent checked when calling from OnSucceeded.

Comment: weird thing...I just noticed that the data from the webmethod is not being seen as an array by the compiler. 
http://pastebin.com/d2236a9w

Comment: I used JSON.Parse and now able to return a proper JSON object. But still getting weird unhandled exceptions. 
Unhandled exception at line 3, column 10284 in http://localhost:7605/Scripts/d3.v3.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Curioser still. Can you use unminified D3 and add details to the question?

Comment: I tried with an un-minified version. I get a "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference" at

function bind(group, groupData) {
      var i, n = group.length,
....

Is there something wrong which is happening that I am doing wrong.

Comment: The code is now working...same code which was not working before is now working. I am bummed.